# Train test split on the basis of date in Python, is it possible?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, data-analysis

I want to split the data on the basis of date as follows:

The data should be divided into:

- train (June 2007 - May 2015) data
- test (June 2015 - Dec 2015) data

Can someone help me with this code?

Comment: You need to provide some code of what you have done so far, what issue you have in your code, and also some more info about your data to get some help here.

Comment: I think it is not hard to split the data based on date, but you have to show your (example) data.

Comment: You shouldn't think of this (if you are) as a `train_test_split` problem. This is just a dataframe split on date range.

Answer (score 0):

You should be more specific by providing a sample of the data you are trying to split.

A typical situation is that where you have a dataframe `df` with a `date` or `timestamp` column. Then, in order to get your train-test split, it is enough to define a mask such as:

```py
import pandas as pd

break_date = pd.Timestamp("2015-06-01 00:00:00")
X = df[df["timestamp"] <= break_date]
y = df[df["timestamp" > break_date]
```

Beware, there are subtleties when splitting data into train and test subsets in the case of time series. For example, see [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/time-series-nested-cross-validation-76adba623eb9).

Comment: Don't you think all values in column `timestamp` should also be converted to pd `Timestamp` objects for this to work. They would be string in a normal data-set.

Comment: String timestamps may be converted to timestamp data types using `pd.to_datetime`. Provided the date strings are ISO, setting `break_date = "2015-06-01 00:00:00"` will work. 
Of course, not having a sample of the data, we do not know what to expect.